# how to reference geometry from curve in blender

Tags: modeling

Im trying to boolean this curve(left) from this cube(middle) and blender doesn't let me to select curve for boolean operation so i need to convert the curve to mesh to perform boolean (right) any idea how can i keep the curve but perform boolean ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the curve live, try using geometry nodes to instance the curve as a mesh object, by creating a mesh object with a geometry nodes modifier that references that curve.  Then you can target it with any number of modifiers that work on meshes but not curves:

[image]

Some traits (like bevel width, created here with profile radius) won't be linked, although you could link those with drivers if you wanted, but the overall shape of the curve will be.

Comment: idk is this possible here to thanks in comments but you saved my life Thanks